# Preload Multiple Fetch Calls in Vue 3 App

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, fetch-api, vue-composition-api

I have a relatively small app that I would like to call multiple api's as the app gets loaded initially and store those results (without Vuex) so that it could be made available via provide/inject to child components.

In my App.vue currently, I have this:

```
export default {
  setup() {
    const data = ref([]);
    const issues = ref([]);

    (async () => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/lists").then({ data });
      data.value = await res.json();
      data.value =
        data.value &&
        data.value.data.map((c) => {
          return { ...c.attributes, id: c.id };
        });
    })();
    (async () => {
      const res = await fetch("/api/issues").then({ issues });
      issues.value = await res.json();
      issues.value =
        issues.value &&
        issues.value.data.map((c) => {
          return [{ ...c.attributes, id: c.id }];
        });
    })();
    provide("items", data);
    provide("issues", issues);

    return {};
  },
  components: {},
```

The items data get's rendered 100% of the time in the child component.  The issues data get's rendered maybe 10% of the time and I'm assuming it's because the async function doesn't finish before the provide statements run.

My questions are

1. Is there a better way to call multiple fetch statements at once and assign those results to a variable I can "provide?"
2. What's the best way to preload these api calls (there's about 3 or 4 more I need to implement) when a user first visits the site and have the results made available without having to re-fetch every time a user switches between views and without using Vuex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-y5hetf

`Promise.all` is for running the fetch calls in parallel, instead of doing it serially which helps improving performance.

As long as you are doing those requests in the `App.vue` file, these calls should only happen on reload, not on route changes.

Comment: I gave that a shot and in the console I got, "[Vue warn]: provide() can only be used inside setup()." and nothing rendered.

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer and added a Stackblitz demo which works now.

Comment: That update for sure fixed the warning, but for some reason I"m still only getting the "issues" data to the child component about 10% of the time. 

Just to give a little more insight, I'm building a data table and there's a few columns from the issues data I add to the items data and then render a table.

Comment: In the stackblitz it works pretty reliable. I've also added a timeout to reset the issues array after a few seconds to check reactivity. Everything seems fine. So it's probably connected to the mapping.

Comment: I’m starting to think that too.  I’m using MirageJS to get the data and it’s adding fields to the data I wouldn’t get in production.  I’m doing that mapping to try to normalize the data.  I really appreciate your help!